# Inheritance: methods

Tags: inheritance

Given the following code:

```
class BaseClass
{
    protected void Do(var param) {}; 
}

class DerivedClass
{
     public void DoSomething()
     {
        var param = something;
        Do(param);
     }
}
```

Is this the proper way to use inheritance? I would think I would have put the "Do" method in a separate class and use composition. However, that would violate encapsulation, as I would have to acces an object in the base class:

```
class DerivedClass
{
   public void DoSomething()
   {
      var param = something;
      base.GetObject().Do(param); 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep that way if good =]
Composition here probably wouldn't break encapsulation, but this seems like an acceptable use of inehritance.